# What budget usb-hub with external power supply would can be used with external HDD?

Tags: usb, hard-disk, hub

I have D-Link DUB-H7 with 7 ports. It works fine except I cannot use my external HDD with it. HDD clicks, but it seems not enough power. Connecting of 2nd HDD's wire doesn't help.

Comment: What's the model number of the HDD you're trying to use?

Comment: @JMY1000 Hitachi 0S00226 Simpledrive MINI SDM/500BD External

Answer (score 1):

## [Anker 4-Port USB 3.0 Ultra-Slim Portable Data Hub with 12W Power Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0192LPK5M) - $16.99

[image]

Based on the fact that your HDD is intended to work with simply a single USB 2.0 port, I'm going to assume that it's simply a bit of a power consumption issue and a simple powered USB hub will fix your issues. There's [a wide variety of USB hubs available](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=powered+usb+hub&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Apowered+usb+hub), but this one is by a reputable manufacturer, comes in a nice form factor, works with or without power, uses USB to deliver additional power, supports USB 3.0, and is fairly cheap.

Comment: Nice to know name of reputable manufacturer, thanks, but my has 7 ports and 4 of them are busy without HDD, so at least 5 necessary. So I would go with 7-port Anker.

Comment: @RS Gotcha, didn't realize that 7 ports on the hub = 7 ports being used

Comment: but 4 will not make sense: I use 4 already and 5-th device is HDD :) So 5 and more gonna be fine.